# Pulling Data from Scratch Org Salesforce DX

Tags: trigger, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Recently started using Salesforce DX. Got a scratch org spun up and pushed some source to it. However I needed to create a new trigger, which I couldn't find a CLI command to do. So I instead created in the UI of the scratch org. Now I'm trying to pull the trigger down to source but can't figure out how to do so.

Questions

1. Is there a salesforce CLI command to create a trigger (sfdx force:apex:?)
2. How can I specify from the CLI that I want to pull down this new trigger?

Answer (score 3):

Use Source [pull](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_pull_md_from_scratch_org.htm) command to pull changes you have in your scratch org to   your local folder

Note that your scratch org is exact replica of source code you have in your local machine

Check the status using the command below before running pull

```
sfdx force:source:status
```

This shows all the changes between local and your org.

Run the below pull command in the project folder

---

```
sfdx force:source:pull
```

I would double check below to make sure I am missing nothing

1. Am I connected to right scratch org
2. Am I running this command inside the project folder .

You can see all the orgs listed using the below command

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

Looks like force:pull somehow does not bring trigger .

Current work around was to crete a trigger.xml file with file name as of trigger.

Sounds like a major flaw and will wait for comments from product team.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, I've done that and each time I get "No Results Found", essentially indicating no differences from source. But I can confirm I've created the trigger in the scratch org UI.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to right scratch org ? I would double check if i am connected to right scratch org and I am running this command inside the project folder .

Comment: No Results found makes me feel you are connected to wrong scratch org .

Comment: See below, I blanked out some info but I only have one scratch org. I believe I'm connected correctly to it: HQ-2040:agentTerm georgealbrecht$ sfdx force:org:list
=== Orgs
     ALIAS  USERNAME                     ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
(D)         george.albrecht@xxx.com  xxxxx  Connected


     ALIAS           SCRATCH ORG NAME        USERNAME                                      ORG IDEXPIRATION DATE
(U)  TermScratchOrg  georgealbrecht Company  test-xxx@georgealbrecht_company.net  xxxx-10-25

Comment: Apologies I don't know how to nicely format above to make that readable but I ran the org list command to show I only have one scratch org.

Comment: Interesting ! Could you then manually create a folder for trigger and then do a source pull .Strange issue !!

Comment: So I already have a folder for "triggers" from when I did my initial metadata pull and then push to source, currently containing two triggers. Should I try deleting that folder?

Comment: I would just locally create a file with trigger name and then run push to see what happens

Comment: Worked by doing it that way, creating the trigger file and the xml file itself. Super weird. Thanks for the help here Mohith!

Comment: Just added workaround to answer .Tweeted to PM of product to see we get any help here

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question below is the command to create the trigger from the SFDX CLI:

```
sfdx force:apex:trigger:create -n mytrigger -s Account -e 'before insert, after upsert' -d <***app-dir***>/main/default/triggers
```

Visit the below link for more details on the creation of trigger from CLI.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_create_trigger.htm

To check the changes b/w the remote and local folder use the below command:

1. If the current scratch org is your default scratch org:

   ```
   sfdx force:source:status
   ```
2. If the current scratch org is not your default scratch org:

   ```
   sfdx force:source:status -u <Scratch Org Alias Name>
   ```

You can pull the data from the scratch org to the local folder using the below command:

1. If the current scratch org is your default scratch org:

   ```
   sfdx force:source:pull
   ```
2. If the current scratch org is your default scratch org:

   ```
   sfdx force:source:pull -u <Scratch Org Alias Name>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

let me start by answering the questions:

1. while we have implemented some scaffolding as you can see with force:apex:class:create, we have not yet implemented the command for triggers.  You can still create the trigger file yourself as long as you follow the conventions.
2. force:source:pull is the command to run to pull down any changes made on the server side.  Triggers are supported and should be working.  I'll work to repro this myself and will log a bug to get fixed asap if its reproducible.

In the mean time try creating a new scratch org and pushing the source to the new org. If it works then my guess is the change tracking somehow got out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the original problem. I have the exact same thing happening.  Created a trigger in (the only) scratch org.  source:status shows no changes, source:pull (obviously) does nothing.

And I confirmed the workaround.  I created a local file, did a source:push.  That overwrote the trigger I had created in the scratch org.